# Whether a certain sequence of functions is pointwise convergent or not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergence-operator, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=nx^n$ , $x \in [0,1)$.

It is given that ${f_n}$ is pointwise convergent.  It is clear that $f_n(0)=0$, and $f_n(x)=0$ ,if $x\in (0,1)$.  But even after excluding $1$ from the domain, points near $1$, the function may exhibit bad behavior. For example:

If $x_n= \sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$ and then $f(x_n)=n^2$, which tends to $\infty$. Again if we take $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$ then $f(x_n)=1$.

As $f(x_n)$ may tend to $\infty$, how can we say that ${f_n}$ is pointwise convergent?

Comment: In the pointwise convergence $x$ is fixed and does not depend on variable $n$.

Comment: But if f_n tends to infinity for any sequence (x_n), can i say it is Point wise convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointwise convergence means that if you **fix** $x_0 \in [0, 1)$, then $f_n(x_0) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ where $f$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n$. In your case, if you fix $x \in [0, 1)$, you know that $n x^n \rightarrow 0$, when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ (and $x$ is fixed, it is point wise convergence). Therefore you can say that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$.

When you consider pointwise convergence you cannot choose $x$ as a function of $n$ because pointwise convergence precisely means that you look at the convergence for a fixed $x$.

However $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $[0, 1)$, and you can see it for example by looking at $f_n(1-1/n)=n(1-1/n)^n \sim n/e \rightarrow + \infty$. Nevertheless uniform convergence is a stronger notion than pointwise convergence.